# phpunit not working on windows

Tags: php, windows, phpunit

I am following these instructions:

> Windows Globally installing the PHAR involves the same procedure as
>   manually installing Composer on Windows:
>
> Create a directory for PHP binaries; e.g., C:\bin
>
> Append ;C:\bin to your PATH environment variable (related help)
>
> Download https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.2.phar and save the file as
>   C:\bin\phpunit.phar
>
> Open a command line (e.g., press Windows+R » type cmd » ENTER)
>
> Create a wrapping batch script (results in C:\bin\phpunit.cmd):
>
> C:\Users\username> cd C:\bin C:\bin> echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %*
>
> > phpunit.cmd C:\bin> exit Open a new command line and confirm that you can execute PHPUnit from any path:
>
> C:\Users\username> phpunit --version PHPUnit x.y.z by Sebastian
>   Bergmann and contributors.

My PHP works because "php -v" returns version etc. but when I run phpunit.cmd i get this:

> P:\phpunit>■@
>
> '■@' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

What am i doing wrong?

EDIT:

running "php phpunit.phar" as suggested by @delboy1978uk gives me the list of commands option for phpunit. So why I get those odd characters?

Comment: Change `echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %*` in your `.bat` to a plain ol `php phpunit.phar` and see if that works

Comment: @delboy1978uk I've updated the question with your suggestion. It works, but I'm still unable to fix my file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely deleted the script file, made one new from scratch, added the line
"php phpunit.phar %*" (without double quotes) and now it works. Maybe an odd file enconding?

Comment: Probably some weird invisible character that got copy/pasted.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I edited the file in notepad to contain exactly this text:

```
php %~dp0phpunit.phar %*
```

Then you have to go to save as, and ensure the encoding type is ANSI when you save it. Then it works as expected.